# I can't reconcile Wordpress and jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I read up on Wordpress and jQuery and found out you can't call `$()` so I switched to no conflict. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/H4EPZ/3/) I have a Fiddle with my problem.

I have viewed the source on the page and copied the html for the menu. I copied in the two JavaScript files which do load and in the correct order. I threw in some alert('LOADED: JS File x') boxes to verify that they load.

I copied the CSS that is relevant to this problem from the style.css from the theme I am creating.

The only problem is that it does what I want and expect it to do. So does anyone know why it wouldn't work in Wordpress?

Comment: I just reverified that both js files load using <code>alert('Loaded MPACT_navigation_tabs.js');</code>. When it is in the top it executes if I put it inside of <code>$j(document).ready( function() { </code> it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is barely answerable bacause it depends on you server code, which you haven't posted. The jsfiddle example is hardly going to help, but here's a couple important points.

> I read up on Wordpress and Jquery and found out you can't call $() so
>   I switched to no conflict.

Yes you can. It all depends on how you include jQuery. WordPress will load it on no conflict mode by default but you can use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [`wp_deregister_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) to prevent the default one and load your own version.

> I copied in the two javascript files which do load and in the correct
>   order. I threw in some alert('LOADED: JS File x') boxes to verify that
>   they load.

The "correct" WordPress way of loading scripts is with the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_register_script` in your `functions.php` file.

Comment: I have used wp_enqueue_script to load both of them with the first being dependent on query h having been having been loaded and the second being dependent on the first having been loaded. see code below.

Comment: function MPACT_namespace_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
   'MPACT_namespace',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/_/js/MPACT_namespace.js',
   array('jquery'), 
   '1.0', 
   false
  );
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'MPACT_namespace_method');
 
    function MPACT_navigation_tabs_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
   'MPACT_navigation_tabs',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/_/js/MPACT_navigation_tabs.js',
   array('MPACT_namespace'), 
   '1.0', 
   false
  );
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'MPACT_navigation_tabs_method');

Comment: ^ @DigitalAcid - it's better if you edit your question, and add this information in, rather than trying to squeeze code into comment boxes. Code is better `formatted` anyway `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If your jQuery code does what you want and expect it to do outside of WordPress as you say, then the problem is with the implementation in WordPress.

as elclanns said you can use the $ sign when working with jQuery in WordPress but it all depends on how its being loaded in your theme.  WordPress ships with a copy of jQuery, and if you use the one they provide you will have to use it in no conflict mode ,meaning you probably wont use the "$".  The Other Option is to deregister the WordPress copy of jQuery and load your own, either from a CDN, or from a local copy that you put in your theme directory.  Note that this will also depend on your theme, I'm assuming this is your own theme, though if its not you will have to hava a look at what being done there.

firstly inspect the source and see if jquery is being loaded. before your other scripts.

if it is, it is either the WP version being enqueued in the head or it is being called in your functions.php.

here are few links to get you started with ensuring jquery is being loaded in the right way,

basic idea :
http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/
(note at te bottom of this page you'll also find a link to an article on how to load js libraries in WP from a CDN)

and a much more involved, but ultimately worthwhile article :
http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/